# Parsing SQL Server number literal with underscore

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I wonder why it works and why it does not return an error:

```
SELECT 2015_11
```

Result:

```
╔══════╗
║ _11  ║
╠══════╣
║ 2015 ║
╚══════╝
```

Second case:

```
SELECT 2.1_a

╔═════╗
║ _a  ║
╠═════╣
║ 2.1 ║
╚═════╝
```

Checking metadata:

```
SELECT  name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
N'SELECT 2015_11', NULL, 0) 
UNION ALL
SELECT  name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
N'SELECT 3.2_a', NULL, 0) 

╔══════╦══════════════════╗
║ name ║ system_type_name ║
╠══════╬══════════════════╣
║ _11  ║ int              ║
║ _a   ║ numeric(2,1)     ║
╚══════╩══════════════════╝
```

While identifier that starts with letter behaves as I think it should:

```
SELECT a_11
-- Invalid column name 'a_11'.
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/450304?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL treats query like

```
SELECT 2015_11
```

as

```
SELECT 2015 _11
```

which is shortcut for

```
SELECT 2015 AS [_11]
```

SQL Server expects column names to  follow some naming convention rules as detailed in this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176104.aspx)

> The names of variables, functions, and stored procedures must comply with the following rules for Transact-SQL identifiers.
>   The first character must be one of the following:
>
> 1. A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z, from
>      A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
> 2. The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).
>
>    Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning in SQL Server. A regular identifier that starts with the at
>      sign always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be used
>      as the name of any other type of object. An identifier that starts
>      with a number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure. An
>      identifier that starts with double number signs (##) denotes a global
>      temporary object. Although the number sign or double number sign
>      characters can be used to begin the names of other types of objects,
>      we do not recommend this practice.
>
> Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not
>   use names that start with @@.

Also the syntax for `SELECT` as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176104.aspx) is like

> SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ] [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] [ WITH TIES
>   ] ]     ::= 
>       { 
>         * 
>         | { table_name | view_name | table_alias }.* 
>         | {
>             [ { table_name | view_name | table_alias }. ]
>                  { column_name | $IDENTITY | $ROWGUID } 
>             | udt_column_name [ { . | :: } { { property_name | field_name } 
>               | method_name ( argument [ ,...n] ) } ]
>             | expression
>             [ [ AS ] column_alias ] 
>            }
>         | column_alias = expression 
>       } [ ,...n ]

In this case the SQL parser first checks for table name, and then column name, Identity and rowguid, and so on till it hits the match with

**| expression  [ [ AS ] column_alias ]**

It then reads literal value till underscore character which is when it realizes that literal must have ended and starts parsing the later characters as **Column_alias** without as explicit `AS`

To verify this try following code in SQL server

```
SELECT 2015AS _11
```

This will produce same results as

```
SELECT 2015_11
```

Also to verify what I just wrote above see the screenshot from SSMS which does a code highlighting on `AS`

[image]

In your first example 2015 is integer literal and in second example 2.1 is decimal literal

In your third example a is not a valid literal. If you try

```
SELECT 'a'_8
```

This will give you result like

```
╔═════╗
║ _8  ║
╠═════╣
║ a   ║
╚═════╝
```

**PS**: You'll see that this works pretty much the same way with # as well

So `SELECT 2015#11` will give similar results

```
╔══════╗
║ #11  ║
╠══════╣
║ 2015 ║
╚══════╝
```

Comment: Could you provide some docs about this behavior? I agree that it could be the case, but it should be mentioned somewhere.

Comment: Underscore triggs "next token" by the scanner. I.e literal 2015 followed by (missing whitespace) and then _11 (valid column alias.)

Answer (score 3):

To understand what is happening, you need to understand what SQL Server accepts as identifiers.  There are a lot of rules, which are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx).  But, the important one is:

> The first character must be one of the following:
>
> 1. A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z, from
>      A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
> 2. The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).

The important point is that when the SQL Server parser encounters a digit, it says to itself:  "This is a number".  When it hits the underscore, it says "Well, no more number, must be starting something else".  The parser recognizes the second component as a valid identifier, so this is treated as:

```
select 2015 _11
```

which is for a column alias, even without the `as`.