# Does SQL have a number separator (like an underscore) to split up large number literals

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to make it easier to read some SQL code where we need to hardcode in some large numbers

I'd like to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT 3_800_000
```

Which, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35988034/1366033), is really treated like this:

```sql
SELECT 3 _800_000
SELECT 3 AS [_800_000]
```

JS allows [numeric separators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator)

```
let x = 1000000000000
let y = 1_000_000_000_000
console.log(x==y) // true
```

Also, C# added [digit separators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-70:%7E:text=Binary%20Literals%20and%20Digit%20Separators) in 7.0 as well

```cs
// These are equivalent.
var bigNumber      = 123456789012345678;
var bigNumberSplit = 123_456_789_012_345_678;
```

Is something similar possible in T-SQL?

**Note**: I'm not looking for a way to format the output, I'm looking for a way to make the source code easier to read for big numbers

Comment: `select @myvalue = Try_Convert(int, Replace('123_456_789','_',''))` - but pointless imho

Comment: `declare @i int = '100' + '000'`  ;-) Not any good way that I'm aware of.

Comment: The answer is no. (At least not in ANSI SQL.)

Comment: No there is no such separator in TSQL. All you can do is comment: `SELECT 3800000 /* 3,800,000 */` or `SELECT 3800000 /* 3.8 million */`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, unfortunately (and as commenters pointed out, thanks folks), that this is not currently a feature of T-SQL.

I was not aware of those JS and C#, so thanks for that.